# Finding $\iiint_{D}x \, dV$ where $D=\left\{x^2+y^2\le1;x,y,z>0;x+y+z<1\right\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, cylindrical-coordinates

I'm trying to solve the following triple integral using cylindrical coordinates:

$$\iiint_{D}x \, dV\,,$$ where   $$D=\left\{x^2+y^2\le1;x,y,z>0;x+y+z<1\right\}$$

This is what I tried to do but I'm not sure how to continue or even if it is all correct. I would love to have you comments and assistance!

[image]

Comment: $1-r\cos\theta-r\sin\theta$ can have negative values. For example, at $\theta=\pi/4$ you get $z=1-r\sqrt 2$. Solving it in Cartesian coordinates is easier

Comment: Given @Andrei's comment, what do you intend the valid values of $z$ to be when $x+y>1$?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure, I mean I can see the issue with $z$ can be negativ, but Im not sure how to use Cartesian coordinates in this case here because either way I have gotten to a point when I'm not sure how to continue. Is the following new domain is the one you intended? $\widetilde{D}=\left\{\left.\left(x,y,z\right)\right|0\le z\le1-x-y;0\le x\le1;0\le y\le\sqrt{1-x^2}\right\}$

Comment: With the constraint that we are in the first octant, the cylinder doesn't actually matter. We are only integrating inside the tetrahedron because it is contained entirely within the cylinder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cylinder doesn't matter at all in this problem because the tetrahedron formed by the plane $x+y+z=1$ and the coordinate planes is contained entirely within the cylinder. So the integral is given by

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} \int_0^{1-x-y}x\:dz\:dy\:dx = \frac{1}{24}$$

Comment: So I'm actually calulating the volume of the tetrahedron ? also how did you chose the range of y? I thought it should be $0\le y\le\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Comment: @ShiranShaharabani why would it be? Did you try drawing the regions and seeing what their intersection looks like?

Comment: Oh I got it, but only after looking on the graphs! thanks a lot